# Javascript : calling document.ready() function of one js file in another php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have progress.js file which has the following code

```
            $('#text_area_input').keyup(function()
            {
                var text_area_box =$(this).val();//Get the values in the textarea
                var max_numb_of_words = 160;//Set the Maximum Number of characters
                var main = text_area_box.length*100;//Multiply the lenght on words x 100
                var value= (main / max_numb_of_words);//Divide it by the Max numb of words previously declared
                var count= max_numb_of_words - text_area_box.length;//Get Count of remaining characters
                if(text_area_box.length <= max_numb_of_words)
                {
                    $('#progressbar').css('background-color','#5fbbde');//Set the background of the progressbar to blue
                    $('#count').html(count);//Output the count variable previously calculated into the div with id= count
                    $('#progressbar').animate(//Increase the width of the css property 'width'
                    {
                        'width': value+'%'
                    }, 1);//Increase the
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#progressbar').css('background-color','yellow');
                    //If More words is typed into the textarea than the specified limit ,
                    //Change the progress bar from blue to yellow
                    var remove_excess_characters =text_area_box.substr(0,max_numb_of_words);
                    $('#text_area_input').val(remove_excess_characters);
                    //Remove the excess words using substring
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

I have to call that function in my php file .
How could i make it right?
And I include all necessary css in my project

Comment: i do not see any function except the anonymous one called when document is ready

Comment: what you want exactly?? Be more specific.

Comment: I have one header.php file like

Comment: I have one header.php file , In header.php i insert some <link> and <script> in head tag and also I include body tag. But in webpage.php file, I have one text area and i apply some jquery to get progress bar dynamically. So I have to call $document.ready function in that webpage.php. But The problem is , I have lot of $document. ready function in header.php which i included in webpage.php. And One more thing I have another head tag in webpage.php which is used for getting JQGrid .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a great solution. Instead of using it in document .ready work like this

```
<input type = 'button' onkeyup = 'my_function();' id = 'text_area_input'>
```

And you script should contain this

```
 <script type = 'text/javascript'>
 function my_function(){
 // you code here
 }
 <script>
```

if you are calling the other php file in this file this function will be available for the new php file too. 
The other solution is that copy the code in the other php file

Answer (score 0):

you can put your jquery code in a seperate file and then include this in your other page using include

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

> I have one header.php file , In header.php i insert some  and  in head tag and also I include body tag. But in webpage.php file, I have one text area and i apply some jquery to get progress bar dynamically. So I have to call $document.ready function in that webpage.php. But The problem is , I have lot of $document. ready function in header.php which i included in webpage.php. And One more thing I have another head tag in webpage.php which is used for getting JQGrid

As I understand you have multiple of document.ready block already, not you want to call a specific block only.

You should change from

```
$(document).ready(
    //code for block 1
)

$(document).ready(
    //code for block 2
)

$(document).ready(
    //code for block 3
)
```

to 
    function codeblock1(){
        //code for block 1
    }

```
function codeblock2(){
    //code for block 2
}

function codeblock3(){
    //code for block 3
}

$(document).ready(
    codeblock1();
    codeblock2();
    ///
)
```

so now you can call any block you want in o ther script